# Jekyll serve --baseurl '' returns error:can't dup TrueClass. Use --trace to view backtrace

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, base-url, github-pages

I'm using gh-pages for depoyment for my jekyll site.

I've been trying to develop without having to delete/add the {{ site.baseurl }} paths back in before all the css, js, and img files for my sources every time I want to serve jekyll locally.

I'm getting a little stuck here as everyone says to pass an empty string like this:

```
jekyll serve --baseurl ""
```

But when I do this it generates the site ok but returns:

```
error: can't dup TrueClass. Use --trace to view backtrace
```

Can't seem to understand why I would be getting this error.

My _config.yml looks more or less like this:

```
url: "http://myjekyllsite.github.io/"
baseurl: "/my-baseurl"
```

I've linked my js and css files as well as added the path to my images like so:

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/img/image1.jpg">
```

The only plugin I'm using is jekyll-sass

Any ideas?

Comment: Is using an absolute path necessary? Why not just use a site root relative URL (i.e. `<img src="/img/image1.jpg">` and then you can just ditch the baseurl stuff.

Comment: Also, if you can link to the repo I'll have a look at your full code.

Comment: Also, try instead of an empty `--baseurl ""` param, do `--baseurl "/"`

Comment: Thanks Joel, using --baseurl "/" led my to my answer below. Of course when I used --baseurl "/" initially the path had a double slash like //img/img1.jpg, so the answer was to remove the forward slash in all my links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a traditional way to fix the dup TrueClass, but I found a good enough way around it so I can develop locally without having to switch those paths each time.

In the guide for gh-pages to jekyll here:
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

They specifically state to not have a trailing slash on your baseurl in your _config.yml. I found by not following their advice and using a trailing slash in _config.yml like so:

```
baseurl: /my-path/
```

I could have all my other links still use the {{ site.baseurl }} path just without the leading slash and use:

```
jekyll serve --baseurl '/' -w
```

So all my paths work just fine.
Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}css/sytle.css">
```

That way it works when I push up to gh-pages too.